# php sample code uses mcrypt which is no longer available in php72

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, mcrypt, opayo

I can see that the sample php code uses mcrypt.

Can we expect that sagepay will re-write the php sample code to use `open_ssl` instead, or perhaps someone has already done it?

Ok, as I've had no response to this, I've tried to find out how to replace the call the `mcrypt` by one to `openssl`.

The original `code` on the encryption side is this :

```
$strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;
//** add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted
$strIn = addPKCS5Padding($strIn);
//** perform encryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
$strCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $strEncryptionPassword, $strIn, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $strIV);
```

And (one of) my attempts at replacing it is this :

```
$strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;    
$strCrypt  = openssl_encrypt($strIn,'AES-128-CBC',$strIV,$options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
//** perform hex encoding and return
return "@" . bin2hex($strCrypt);
```

I've tried the `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` options and also `"AES_192_CBC"` as well as `"AES_256_CBC"`.

I am comparing a before and after string encrypted for mcrypt  (and successfully processed by Sagepay), but not getting the same encrypted string from `openssl`.

I'd appreciate some help.

ok, I think I've got this to work, although I am not sure exactly what I had to do different from what I'd tried before, here's the code for the two functions in the Sagepay interface package:

```
Define('SESS_CIPHER','AES-128-CBC');
function NEWencryptAndEncode($strIn) {  
global $strEncryptionType
      ,$strEncryptionPassword;
if ($strEncryptionType=="XOR") 
{
    //** XOR encryption with Base64 encoding **
    return base64Encode(simpleXor($strIn,$strEncryptionPassword));
} 
else 
{
    //** AES encryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding then HEX encoding - DEFAULT **
    //** use initialization vector (IV) set from $strEncryptionPassword
$strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;    
//** add PKCS5 padding to the text to be encypted
$strIn = addPKCS5Padding($strIn);
//** perform encryption with PHP's Openssl module
    $strCrypt  = openssl_encrypt($strIn, SESS_CIPHER,$strIV,$options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,$strIV);   
    //** perform hex encoding and return
    return "@" . bin2hex($strCrypt);
}}
```

and

```
function NEWdecodeAndDecrypt($strIn) {
global $strEncryptionPassword;
if (substr($strIn,0,1)=="@") 
{
    //** HEX decoding then AES decryption, CBC blocking with PKCS5 padding - DEFAULT ** 
    //** use initialization vector (IV) set from $strEncryptionPassword
    $strIV = $strEncryptionPassword;    
    //** remove the first char which is @ to flag this is AES encrypted
    $strIn = substr($strIn,1);      
    //** HEX decoding
    $strIn = pack('H*', $strIn);    
    //** perform decryption with PHP's MCRYPT module
    return openssl_decrypt($strIn, SESS_CIPHER,$strIV,$options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,$strIV); 
} 
else 
{
    //** Base 64 decoding plus XOR decryption **
    return simpleXor(base64Decode($strIn),$strEncryptionPassword);
}}
```

Comment: Please provide more information on the sample code you are using and on *sagepay*...

Comment: Sagepay is a Credit Card processing merchant in the UK, and they provide sample php code to use in creating webpages to interface to their systems.  The sample code they provide (still - I checked yesterday) uses the mcrypt decode and encode to code up the transaction before sending it to them using (I think) a POST request.

Comment: Sagepay support send you to here to get technical help, so I am hoping that one fo the support staff will be along to comment soon.

Comment: That seems like a strange unusual process. Have you tried contacting the support at https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support ?

Comment: yes, the website sends me to here with the tag [sagepay]

Comment: Have you seen [this gist](https://gist.github.com/odan/c1dc2798ef9cedb9fedd09cdfe6e8e76)? The difference I see is that "$iv" is also being passed through, as is your original mcrypt function.

Comment: I think the difference between that useage and mine is that the encrypt and decrypt will work with each other, whereas I am needing to duplicate the action of mcrypt as the sagepay server will decrypt it I guess using mcrypt or similar.